# RSI outputs in Technical Trading Rules (TTR) package

Tags: r

I'm learning to use R's capability in technical trading with Technical Trading Rules (TTR) package. Assume a crypto portfolio and BTC its reference currency. Historical hourly data (60 period) is collected using [cryptocompare.com API](https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/) and converted to `zoo` object. The aim is to create a 14-period RSI for each crypto (and possibly visualize all in one canvas). For each crypto, I expect RSI output to be 14 `NA` followed by 46 calculated values. But I'm getting 360 outputs. What am I missing here?

```
require(jsonlite)
require(dplyr)
require(TTR)

portfolio <- c("ETH", "XMR", "IOT")

for(i in 1:length(portfolio)) {
  hour_data <- fromJSON(paste0("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histohour?fsym=", portfolio[i], "&tsym=BTC&limit=60", collapse = ""))
  read.zoo(hour_data$Data) %>%
    RSI(n = 14) %>%
    print()
}
```

Also, my time series data is in the following form (first column timestamp):

```
            close   high    low   open volumefrom  volumeto
1506031200 261.20 264.97 259.78 262.74    4427.84 1162501.8
1506034800 258.80 261.20 255.68 261.20    2841.67  735725.4
```

Does TTR use more conventional OHLC (open, high, low, close) order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RSI()` function expects a univariate price series. You passed it an object with 6 columns, so it converted that to a univariate vector. You need to subset the output of `read.zoo()` so that only the `"close"` column is passed to `RSI()`.

Comment: Wonderful. `RSI(read.zoo(hour_data$Data)[, 2], n = 14)` works. I didn't know math behind RSI (that is only needs closing price).

Comment: @moazzem: yeah, I'd like it to be "smarter", but that's hard in its current state, because there's no nice way to *know* which column to use if the object has more than one column.  The best hint with TTR functions is the name of the argument.  If it's `OHLC`, then the function needs OHLC prices, `HL` needs high-low prices, etc.  If it's just `price`, then it's a univariate price.  If it's `x`, then it could be price, volume, or any series.

Comment: I'm entirely new to crypto as well as R. TTR is an excellent package. I will first work on the maths behind indicators and gradually make the script "smarter" as I learn.